# sql query need to check date along with Store_id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, both has millions of rows.

```
Table A:-
Store_id, Purchase_dt, Amount
--------  -----------  ------
1001       02JAN19     12.20
1001       05MAY20     13.30
1002       07JUL21     10.97

Table B:- 

Store_id, Valid_from, Valid_to, Profile_ID
--------  ----------  --------  ----------
1001      01JAN17     08JUL19    56
1001      09JUL19     12DEC99    60
1002      01JAN20     12DEC99    70
```

I need to find only transaction from stores that has a profile id of 60 and 70 and Purchase_dt should be between Valid_from and valid_to and for this joining column is Store_id.

Target table expectation is:

```
Store_id, Purchase_dt, Amount, Profile_ID
--------  -----------  ------
1001       05MAY20     13.30    60
1002       07JUL21     10.97    70
```

I tried with

```
Select
a.Store_id,
a.Purchase_dt,
a.Amount,
b.Profile_ID
from
table_a a,
table_b b
where
a.Store_id = b.Store_id
and
a.Purchase_dt between b.Valid_from and b.Valid_to
and 
b.Profile_ID in (60,70)
```

but not getting the desired result, all dates are date data type  any help is appreciated!

Comment: in your Valid_to comment it reads 99 as 1999 and not 2099 and that's why you're not getting any results back.

Comment: its date data type and its 2099

Comment: While it is weird that you are using a join syntax that got out of fashion in the 1990s, your query is still correct. What exactly does "not getting the desired result" mean? Are you getting more rows than you should? Less rows that you should? Dates joined to a wrong profile? "not getting the desired result" doesn't tell us anything.

Answer (score 1):

If dates are really stored as strings (that's what sample data you posted looks like), then - if you want `between` to work properly - you first have to convert these strings into valid `DATE` datatype values (using `to_date` function with appropriate format model).

Moreover, you're looking for trouble keeping 2-digits years; didn't Y2K bug teach you anything?

I'd suggest you to keep dates in `DATE` datatype columns and avoid many kinds of problems.

As of your current problem, here you are:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  table_a (store_id, purchase_dt, amount) as
  3    (select 1001, '02JAN19', 12.20 from dual union all
  4     select 1001, '05MAY20', 13.30 from dual union all
  5     select 1002, '07JUL21', 10.97 from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_b (store_id, valid_from, valid_to, profile_id) as
  8    (select 1001, '01JAN17', '08JUL19', 56 from dual union all
  9     select 1001, '09JUL19', '12DEC99', 60 from dual union all
 10     select 1002, '01JAN20', '12DEC99', 70 from dual
 11    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 12  select a.store_id, a.purchase_dt, a.amount, b.profile_id
 13  from table_a a join table_b b
 14         on a.store_id = b.store_id
 15        and to_date(a.purchase_dt, 'ddMONyy') between
 16            to_date(b.valid_from, 'ddMONyy') and to_date(b.valid_to, 'ddMONyy')
 17  where b.profile_id in (60, 70);

  STORE_ID PURCHAS     AMOUNT PROFILE_ID
---------- ------- ---------- ----------
      1001 05MAY20       13,3         60
      1002 07JUL21      10,97         70

SQL>
```

---

If - as you commented - date values really are `DATE`s - then it gets simpler.

Compare:

- Strings:

  ```
   15        and to_date(a.purchase_dt, 'ddMONyy') between
   16            to_date(b.valid_from, 'ddMONyy') and
  ```

to_date(b.valid_to, 'ddMONyy')

- Dates:

  ```
  15        and a.purchase_dt between b.valid_from and b.valid_to
  ```

The whole query that deals with `DATE` datatype:

```
SQL> with
  2  table_a (store_id, purchase_dt, amount) as
  3    (select 1001, date '2019-01-02', 12.20 from dual union all
  4     select 1001, date '2020-05-05', 13.30 from dual union all
  5     select 1002, date '2021-07-07', 10.97 from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_b (store_id, valid_from, valid_to, profile_id) as
  8    (select 1001, date '2017-01-01', date '2019-07-08', 56 from dual union all
  9     select 1001, date '2019-07-09', date '2099-12-12', 60 from dual union all
 10     select 1002, date '2020-01-01', date '2099-12-12', 70 from dual
 11    )
 12  select a.store_id, a.purchase_dt, a.amount, b.profile_id
 13  from table_a a join table_b b
 14         on a.store_id = b.store_id
 15        and a.purchase_dt between b.valid_from and b.valid_to
 16  where b.profile_id in (60, 70) ;

  STORE_ID PURCHASE     AMOUNT PROFILE_ID
---------- -------- ---------- ----------
      1001 05.05.20       13,3         60
      1002 07.07.21      10,97         70

SQL>
```

---

**Your query** applied to same sample data also works:

```
SQL> with
  2  table_a (store_id, purchase_dt, amount) as
  3    (select 1001, date '2019-01-02', 12.20 from dual union all
  4     select 1001, date '2020-05-05', 13.30 from dual union all
  5     select 1002, date '2021-07-07', 10.97 from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_b (store_id, valid_from, valid_to, profile_id) as
  8    (select 1001, date '2017-01-01', date '2019-07-08', 56 from dual union all
  9     select 1001, date '2019-07-09', date '2099-12-12', 60 from dual union all
 10     select 1002, date '2020-01-01', date '2099-12-12', 70 from dual
 11    )
```

This is your query:

```
 12    Select
 13  a.Store_id,
 14  a.Purchase_dt,
 15  a.Amount,
 16  b.Profile_ID
 17  from
 18  table_a a,
 19  table_b b
 20  where
 21  a.Store_id = b.Store_id
 22  and
 23  a.Purchase_dt between b.Valid_from and b.Valid_to
 24  and
 25  b.Profile_ID in (60,70);

  STORE_ID PURCHASE     AMOUNT PROFILE_ID
---------- -------- ---------- ----------
      1001 05.05.20       13,3         60
      1002 07.07.21      10,97         70

SQL>
```

Comment: dates field are date datatype

Comment: Then it gets even simpler; see edited answer.

Comment: this works thanks but how come mine is not working, I am also performing inner join

Comment: It is working, at least with sample data you provided. Have a look at edited answer.

Comment: For bigger tables this is not working.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Table size doesn't matter (unless you're "longer time of execution because of lot of data" calling "not working"). So, what is actually "not working"? Did you get any error? If so, which one?

Comment: after running the above , I try to verify it by taking the distinct minus query on Store_id.

Comment: some Store_id whose purchase_dt is between valid_from and valid_to still they are not coming in the output(they have a profile in condition 60)

Comment: Can't tell why. Post relevant sample data (by editing the question, not as a comment) so that we'd see what's going on.